# Unable to get page full url in Login Page in Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, redirect, liquid

I have been working on the redirecting a user to some URL based upon the page he clicks login on.

So, I have a registration page, and a normal page, both have the login button. So when a user clicks the login page from the registration page, he/she should be redirected to some other page, and in case of normal one, he/she should be redirected to account page.

What I have done is I have added params to the URL, when the user hits the login page from the registration page in order to differentiate it. Now the final touch up is remaining since the params are added, but I want the user to be redirected to my desired URL based upon the URL in the login page.

I know how to redirect the user to some specific location using this.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ 'customer.login.sign_in' | t }}">
<input type="hidden" name="checkout_url" value="YOUR URL" />
```

But I want a check like this if the URL is **X**, then `<input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ 'customer.login.sign_in' | t }}">` this should implpement else

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ 'customer.login.sign_in' | t }}">
<input type="hidden" name="checkout_url" value="YOUR URL" />
```

Now the problem is I have tried enough to get the URL, but now getting one. I have done the operation like this :

```
{% if page.url == 'X'%}
    OPERATION 1
{% else %}
    OPERATION 2
{% endif %}
```

Now, the problem is, the check is not working at all, and every time it performs else condition.

I have used only if condition also in order to check whether it works, like placing a dummy text inside the if condition like this :

```
{% if page.url == 'X'%}
   <p>Working!!</p>
{% endif %}
```

**NOTE:** I have not used the domain, all I have used is the part except the domain, that is `/account/login?params=hello`

Came out that the text is not at all visible. I have also used the **site.url** but not working out.

I need your help, since **page.url** must work, but in this case it is not at all working.

I have made one javascript function to get the params in the page, but I don't know how to put it into the `{% if %}`!

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
  function GetURLParameter(sParam){
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++){
      var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam){
          return sParameterName[1];
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = window.GetURLParameter('params'); 
</script>
```

I could get the value inside my **HTML** but don't know how to do it in **IF**

```
<p id="name"></p>
```

Please help, if any one of the solutions suits you. I just need a little more help from you guys, and I will be done.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in Liquid method to return the querystring values in a url with Shopify Liquid. A work around is defined [here using content_for_header](https://freakdesign.com.au/blogs/news/get-the-url-querystring-values-with-liquid-in-shopify). However, you can simply do that using JavaScript. Check code comments and adapt accordingly.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // uncomment below line to get actual url from browser
    //var url_string = window.location.href;
    var url_string = "http://www.example.com/?source=diff-page";
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    
    // Get the param value if exist
    var source = url.searchParams.get("source");
    
    // Get input elements by nmae
    var input = document.getElementsByName("checkout_url");
    
    // check if any input element with that name exist
    if (input.length > 0) {
    
        // check if returned param is not empty and equal to our condition
        if (source !== null && source == "diff-page") {
            // change the value
            input[0].value = "something different";
        } else {
            input[0].value = "something default";
        }
        // log for testing purpose
        console.log(input[0].value);
    }

});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="checkout_url" value="YOUR URL" />
```